# predis hmset nested array in value

Tags: php, redis, predis

I am using predis php client.
My code is like:

```
$ObjArray = get_object_vars ( $obj );     
$redis->hmset("post:4545",$objArray);
```

ObjArray is like:
array(
    "id" => 1212,
    "name" => "test",
    "likes" => array(1,2,3),
    "comments" => array(0=>(1,2,3),1=>(1,2,3))

With this I get the error:
redis ERR Protocol error: invalid bulk length

Can't we have array in value of redis hashe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis hashes are not multidimensional so field values can only be strings. The values in `likes` and `comments` in your `$ObjArray` variable are arrays which means they are not good, you should either serialize them (JSON or whichever serialization format you prefer) or store them into different and separate keys.

Comment: thats right, `json stringify` seems a solution for arrays in this case

Answer (score 1):

I think i am very late to answer this, but someone may find this answer useful.

Use json_encode while saving the multidiomentional data and use json_decode after getting the data from Redis

Answer (score 0):

I have never used predis but little researched showed that may be you will have to serialize your object as predis does not serialize your object automatically.

More information on below link

https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/29